# Django routing sending me to the wrong URL

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, sqlite

I'm in the process of creating a small poll app with Django and the main page has a button that allows the user to create new polls and another one that allows them to delete polls.

My delete route should send the user to a confirmation page that would be located at /polls/:id/delete. When I type it in the URL it works but when I try to access the confirmation page via button click it sends me to the wrong URL.

I've tried changing information in the deletePoll class and in the Path but neither work.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
#this is my form on the page: 

<form action="{% url 'polls:delete' pk=question.id %}"method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
<input class="btn btn-default btn-danger" type="submit"value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

```css
#this is my class inside of views.py

class PollDelete(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'polls/delete.html'
    # can specify success url
    # url to redirect after sucessfully
    # deleting object
    def get_object(request):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        return render(request, 'polls/delete.html')
```

```html
#this is my polls/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    #path for delete
    #Tried changing the format to /polls/delete/PK but it didn't work
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.PollDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
    # path('createpoll/', views.createPoll, name='createPoll')
]
```

Comment: "sends me to the wrong URL" please specify which url does it take you to. From your code everything looks fine.

Comment: When I click on the button it currently sends me to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/delete.html" instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/delete/

Earlier it was sending me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/delete/polls. 
I think my understanding of Django routing is a bit flawed but that's what's going on

Comment: Why do you write `return render(request, 'polls/delete.html')` in your `get_object` method? `get_object` is supposed to return the object that is to be deleted. So you should be writing `return question`. Also where does the variable `question_id` come from in that method??

Comment: It's my first time using Django so the delete view was created following an online tutorial. 
The question_id comes from the Question model that's imported in this view.

Comment: you say question_id comes from `Question` model. But does importing the model mean you automatically get a variable in your file like that? Are you creating a **global** variable `question_id`? (I advice you not to use global variables with Django) most likely you want the id from the kwargs so you should write `question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])`. In fact that leads me to notice you write `get_object(request)` but it should really be `get_object(self)`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat well my vote function was build very similarly and the delete function did too. I used your code and it seems to work exactly the same it did before. 

I really thought the return render is needed since the question will be erased, I want to send the users to the previous page again.

Answer (score 0):

```
path('delete/<int:pk>', views.PollDelete.as_view(), name='delete')
```

paste this code to your urls.py. the action in your html recognizes delete/pk, you are throwing pk/delete/ to your url which does not return the proper url.